# How can you calibrate a touch screen on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: touchscreen, xinput

I have recently given up with the wonderful Windows XP and made the switch to Ubuntu. It is a wonderful operating system that has come very far since I last used it!

My problem has been that no matter how hard I try, I can't get my touch screen to calibrate.

I have a Panasonic Toughbook CF-30 that I brought off ebay a few weeks ago. It is a wonderful piece of machinery, and ran XP beautifully. I payed a little extra for the touchscreen model.

In XP, I grabbed the driver off the Panasonic website that gave me a simple tool to align the screen.

Since in by default (w/o calibration) the screen is offset, I have been trying to calibrate it for use in Ubuntu.

I found out about xinput_calibrator, and have tried the 99-calibration file to no effect. It seems to completley ignore any calibration data, even modding the evdev file.

Help would be appreciated as to how I can calibrate the touch screen.

Just a note it is not multi touch.

Thanks a lot!